# Is this database normalized

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I'm trying to build a strong database that's normalized and has room to expand if needed. Does this look like I might have problems? Could this be more efficient? Most importantly, is this database normalized the best it could be? Thanks for having a look!

[image]

**EDIT I**

I'll try and explain my many to many relationships.

Attributes: This site plans of carrying guns, ammunition, accessories, and etc ... each product can have many attributes and some could have one. For example, ammunition for a rimfire, handgun, and centerfire will have the same attributes while shotguns will have different attributres. So my thought is that in order to make attributes flexible I needed to have the tables set-up like I have in my example. Hopefully that makes sense -  I did struggle with this.

Supplier: There can be multiple suppliers for a product.

Images - Products will have a main picture and an unknown amount of additional images.

Categories: A product could appear in multiple categories. Example, a firearm could appear in semiautomatic rifles as well as tactical firearms.

Reviews: A single product will have multiple reviews.

PLEASE DISREGARD the "new field" fields in the product table. That is unattended, I forgot to remove those before the screenshot.

**EDIT II**

I redesigned the schema using everyone's suggestions. Please take a look and see if I'm getting closer. I really appreciate everyone's time on this ;)

[image]

Comment: Usually pluralize the name of the tables, whatever seems to be optimally.

Comment: @ PiLHA -  I see what you're saying since there will be multiple records. Thanks-

Comment: @John Woo - I will try to explain my thought in my post in-case others have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to have *many-to-many* relationship between `product` and `attributes`? Can an attribute belongs to multiple product as well? If not, remove the `product_attributes` table. Create a column called `attribute_id` on the table `product` a reference it to table `attributes` on column `attribute_id`.

I also think that the relationship between `product` and `images` table is only *one-to-many*. Delete the table `images` and create a new column in table `product_images` called `image_path`. Do this also with `product` and `reviews`.

I found many many-to-many relationship in your schema.

Always remember that joining a table is very expensive for the application level.

Comment: Great information John! I'm going to rework my schema with your suggestions. Thanks so much!

Comment: This time, I think you need to have another table for `Product` and `Manufactor` since a product have be manufacture by multiple company as well as manufacturer could have multiple products.

Comment: Hey John, what do you think of the updated schema?

Comment: @Mike i'm concern with your `Product` and `Supplier`. It should have direct relationship with each other because for some reason there are times when `product` can have multiple `suppier` but a single `manufacturer`. In that case, you will have invalid result when you try to join those tables. Uhmm, did you get my point?

Comment: I see what you are saying. A gun (or other product) could have multiple suppliers ... makes sense. So I will change the table as follows: | supplier_id | product_id | supplier_name | . How doeas that look? I feel like I will never understand this stuff. I am good with PHP/PDO, but databases are kicking my a$$ ;)

Comment: @Mike I think it would be better if you create all referencing IDs on products table example for `Products` table and `Images`. Remove `product_id` column for table images and creat a column name `images_id` on products table and create a contraint that references the column on `images` table's primary key. For `supplier`, add a `supplier_ID` column on `product` table and reference it to `suppliers` table's primary key also.

Answer (score 2):

Why are there two "new field"s in the Products table?  Why are review_id and attribute_id in the Products table when they appear to be linked through junction tables?

Does a single image really show more than one product?  If not, you don't need or want product_images, just put product_id into the images table.  Same question with reviews; does a single review cover multiple products?  If not, remove the junction table.

Do products really have both a supplier AND a manufacturer?  Is it really true that each manufacturer supplies only a single product?

What is your thinking behind the key-value mechanism you've set up for attributes?

Is there any particular reason you've decided on additional id columns in tables like categories and attributes rather than using the natural keys?

Comment: Very good eye, I cannot believe I didn't pay attention to the product table closer than I did. What happened was I laid out the table and as I made the tables forgot to delete the fields I made tables for. I'm struggling with many-> many relationships for some reason. So should I NOT have the link tables? Should I include the id of the tables in the product table?

Comment: It's not a matter of whether linking tables are good or bad.  It's a matter of how to correctly represent the data.  So, if one image can be linked to multiple products (eg, you have a photo that shows 3 different models and the photo should appear on the product page for each model) then, yes, a linking table is appropriate.  If that will never happen because you photograph each product separately, then you don't need the linking table and, if you don't need it you shouldn't have it.

Comment: Gotcha, you are correct! Each product will have it's own unique image.

Comment: @ Larry - I removed the erroneous fields and removed the junction tables. I have a couple of questions; let's start with images. If I have one table how do I insert multiple image paths? I'm learning about this the best I can so please excuse me if this seems like an elementary question.

Comment: You just need table Images (or ProductImages, as you prefer) with columns (ProductID, ImagePath).  If you want to designate one-and-only-one of these to be the PrimaryImage, you would add a column in the Products table that holds either the ImagePath of that image or (if you want an extra integer value in Images) the ImageID.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you are saying, makes sense. Second question; the attributes table was hard for me and I asked SO on ideas and what I am using was the best suggestion. Here is the question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605104/how-to-lay-out-my-database     is there a better way to achieve what I want?